# Get AppId for Windows Metro apps

Tags: c#, windows, windows-store-apps

My c# application enumerates all Metro (or modern UI style) apps installed from Windows Store. I would also like to construct a link to to applications' Windows Store page. For example Skype has following URL:
http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/skype/5e19cc61-8994-4797-bdc7-c21263f6282b

I have understood last part (5e19cc61-8994-4797-bdc7-c21263f6282b) is application GUID or AppId. How can I get this programmatically? While enumerating apps and parsing AppxManifest.xml and resources.pri there is no reference to this GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could simply get the `GUID`.

```
string appId = CurrentApp.AppId.ToString();
```

For more have a look at here:

http://www.wadewegner.com/2012/09/getting-the-application-id-and-hardware-id-in-windows-store-applications/

Hope it helps!

Comment: That function only works from inside an app, getting GUID to current application? I am trying to enumerate other installed applications.